# Why is my custom Android View not showing up twice?

Tags: android, view, drawable

I have the following class in an Android project:

```
public class Island extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

    public Island(Context context) {
        super(context);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int width = 50;
        int height = 50;

        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }

    public void change() {
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Why am I not able to multiple circles to my layout? Say I have a vertical LinearLayout, then in my on create, I do:

```
layout.addView(new Island(this));
layout.addView(new Island(this));
```

Only one circle shows up instead of two different circles. I can't figure out why this is happening. Any idea what is happening to the other circle? Thanks for any ideas.

Edit:
I also tried adding the circles and setting their width and heights to wrap_content, and only one shows up still.

Comment: They're the same size at the same position.  You're probably seeing both, but don't know it b/c they're on top of each other.

Comment: I realized if I set the width and height to a specific value, it spaces them and I can see them. Is there any way to make wrap_content make the view only as big as the drawn circles?

Comment: It sounds like you want `wrap_content` to know the size before it is created so that it can be created at the right size?

Comment: I think so? Is there a way to explicitly define how big the View is so wrap_content knows how big to make it?

Comment: That's a whole 'nother question and I don't know the answer off hand as I haven't tried. I usually size it and then draw to account for the size inside.  If you know the content size, why the need to have `wrap_content` to determine it?  Anyway, I'd delete this question and post a question which addresses your actual needs to get those more familiar with this part of Views a chance to answer.